# After Domain Upgrade, why can't 2008R2 servers connect to one of the new DCs?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2016

we recently upgraded our domain to Windows Server 2016. We have two new DCs running on domain functional level 2016, removed the old DCs and now we seem to have a strange issue.

Our old servers with Windows Server 2008 R2 (VMs and physical machines alike) cannot connect to DC2, be it via SMB, kerberos constrained delegation etc. They can ping DC2 but cannot access any service that requires authentication. That all works for our DC1 however - The 2012(R2), 2016 Servers and Windows 10 clients can access both DCs without any issues.

Since the DC2 runs the new PKI, I thought that this might be the error, but i was rather baffled, that all the respective 2008 R2 servers had valid certificates issued by that PKI, so that is not the problem.

For example: Connections to port 445 on DC2 are definitely accepted, the Server 2008 tries to negotiate SMB protocol, recieves the server settings, however when initiating the SMB connection DC2 immediately responds with an access denied message.

The plan is to replace/upgrade the remaining Servers to 2016 in the near future, but that will take some time and I do need them to authenticate properly (especially kereberos constrained delegation is really messing up) right now.

Any ideas why just one DC is denying any request while the other does not?

Comment: Any event at DC2 that you may follow? Specially in the security log. If not, make sure the audition of failed events are activated.

Comment: The audit policy is set to log succesful and failed for both DCs but I do not see any audit failed log entries, just audit successful.

Comment: That's... surprising! If your problem would be just about SMB, I would check SMB versions, just to be sure. But about the Kerberos...

Comment: Okay it was actually two separate problems. Your comment led me to checking the SMB settings and one of the DCs was set to deny unsigned SMB requests. The Kerberos issue was due to a wrong SPN entry in the firewall rule - which should have updated properly via GP which wasn't available due to the SMB issue...

Comment: Well, even if I'd no clue, glad my comment lit a bulb! ;-)